# Amazon EC2 hostnames

Tags: amazon-ec2, xmpp

I'm currently trying to setup a Tigase cluster on Amazon EC2 instances in a VPC and I'm having troubles getting it to work due to the hostnames of the instances not being "full DNS names". According to the Tigase documentation:

> Please note the proper DNS configuration is critical for the cluster
>   to work correctly. Make sure the 'hostname' command returns a full DNS
>   name on each cluster node.

Can anyone explain what a full DNS name is and how I can set my instances to use one? Currently my instances get a default hostname of the form "ip-10-0-0-20".

Comment: Are you talking about a Fully Qualified Domain name? eg: hostname.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the "hostname" command on whatever OS you've got running on your EC2 instance.  This isn't going to give you the FQDN.  Instead, check the instance properties/details page in the AWS console.  IIRC, you should see an internet FQDN as well as an internal FQDN (i.e. for instance-to-instance communication).

I'm not familiar with Tigase, but if it's picky about the guest OS knowing it's own FQDN, you can specify the domain portion in the resolv.conf file.

Comment: I'm actually running the instances within a VPC which from what I found on this site (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html) EC2 in VPC receive an unresolvable host name that AWS assigns. I'm wondering if setting up a custom option set with a domain name and using AmazonProvidedDNS would work?

Comment: You could try that... or you could try creating a new EC2 instance and set it up as a DNS server using the software of your choice.  Then just create records for the instances functioning as Tigase nodes.